# Array of functions don't keep their values from their creation

Tags: swift, xcode, function, chain

I try to manage my functions with a Manger. The problem is that the function code updates and is not saved in the moment when i add the function to my manager. I try to explain my problem with this example:

```
class QueueManager {

    typealias FunctionType = () -> ()

    private var functions = [(String, FunctionType)]()

    func add(funcName: String, function: FunctionType) -> QueueManager {
        functions.append(funcName, function)
        return self
    }

    func runFirst() -> Bool {
        guard functions.isEmpty == false else { return false }
        functions.first!.1()
        functions.removeFirst()
        return true
    }
}
```

Then i do this:

```
let queueManager = QueueManger()

var value = 1

queueManager.add("simpleFunction"){
    print(value)
}

value = 2

queueManager.add("simpleFunction"){
    print(value)
}

queueManager.runFist()
queueManager.runFist()
```

And the result is:

```
2 // Because value is 2 in both functions. But i added the function while value was 1??
2
```

But i want the result:

```
1
2
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Very easy playground example:**

```
import UIKit


var str = "1"
func go() {
    print(str)
}

var array:[()->()] = []
array.append(go)

str = "2"

array.append(go)
array[0]()
array[1]()

// Output:
// 2
// 2
```

**EDIT 2:** 
I know that 2 2 is the right output for my code. But i want to keep the function in the state of its creation. Is this somehow possible?

**EDIT 3:**
Thanks for all of your help. But i think i`m failing to explain my problem enough to get suiting answers. I want to call a function with its parameters at a later time. I don't want to keep the reference to the parameter values. I just need to call the function with those parameter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand what happens here lets take a look step-by-step :

1. Assign 1 to value
2. Add the print instruction to `QueueManager`
3. Assign 2 to value
4. Add the print instruction to `QueueManager`
5. Run the functions using `runFirst()`

When you add the `print(value)` instruction you pass `value` as reference type. This creates a strong reference between variable `functions` and `value`. Hence when you actually execute those instructions, using `runFirst()` it then uses the value stored in `value` at that point of time.

Let's explore using this example:

```swift
var value = 5

queueManager.add(funcName: "simpleFunction"){
    print(value)
}

queueManager.add(funcName: "simpleFunction"){
    print(value)
}

queueManager.runFirst()
queueManager.runFirst()

value = 10

// output is 5  5
```

In this case we perform `runFirst()` first and then update the value. Hence the output is `5  5`.

TL;DR - Pass By Reference causes function to print the current value of variable `value`.

EDIT : Bind the data to the function in `QueueManager`, this will make sure that the current value of data (during function definition) is associated with the function.

```swift
class QueueManager {

    typealias FunctionType = (Int) -> ()
    private var functions = [(String, FunctionType, Int)]()

    func add(funcName: String, function: @escaping FunctionType, data: Int) -> QueueManager
    {
        functions.append((funcName, function, data))
        return self
    }

    func runFirst() -> Bool
    {
        guard functions.isEmpty == false else { return false }
        functions.first!.1(functions.first!.2)
        functions.removeFirst()
        return true
    }
}

let queueManager = QueueManager()

// define you function within this closure
let functionClosure: (Int) -> () = { (data) in
    print(data)
}

var value = 1
queueManager.add(funcName: "simpleFunction", function: functionClosure, data: value)

value = 2
queueManager.add(funcName: "simpleFunction", function: functionClosure, data: value)

queueManager.runFirst()
queueManager.runFirst()
```

OUTPUT :

```
1
2
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the function in the state of its creation? I want to call it at a later time with the value it has when i added it.

Comment: Sure, all you need to do is make sure you pass by value. I have updated the answer with the simplest way of achieving this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But that seems like a really dirty solution. I manage over 100 functions with this. If i would create new variables for each of the function i would create more than 1000 new values. There must be some other way to archive this. In other languages its possible too.

Comment: Really? I doubt if it will be possible in this way. You are trying to have your function compute (in this case mutate) the value of a stored property BEFORE it's own execution.

Comment: No. The variable Value can change. I don't even need the reference to it. I just need its value from the time its been added to the function as an parameter. I just want to keep the call of the function with its parameter values to call them later all together. But maybe i`m just failing in explaining what i want to archive. Sorry for wasting your time then :/

Comment: I think I follow you. What you can do is create a array called data in your queue manager. Then change FunctionType to accept an Int as a param. Then in the add func you associate data to the func. Now when add a func to the array of functions you also add the relevant value to the array of data. Hope you can figure it out. I'm AFK right now. Will update the answer soon if you can't figure it out.

Comment: That's what i`m doing. But i was hoping for a better solution. But maybe there is none.

Comment: It is possible. Check the latest edit. I've had to modify things a bit but it should accomplish what you want and should work with your real project as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, obviously the result should be:

```
2
2
```

because you are calling `queueManager.runFirst()` tow times *after* editing `value = 2`

Also, if `add` function should includes `functions.append((funcName, function))` then I assume that its `function` parameter should be `@escaping` as follows:

```
class QueueManager {
    typealias FunctionType = () -> ()

    private var functions = [(String, FunctionType)]()

    func add(funcName: String, function: @escaping FunctionType) -> QueueManager {
        functions.append((funcName, function))
        return self
    }

    func runFirst() -> Bool {
        guard functions.isEmpty == false else { return false }
        functions.first!.1()
        functions.removeFirst()
        return true
    }
}
```

Thus the output of:

```
let queueManager = QueueManager()

var value = 1

queueManager.add(funcName: "simpleFunction") { 
    print(value)
}

queueManager.runFirst()

value = 2

queueManager.add(funcName: "simpleFunction"){
    print(value)
}

queueManager.runFirst()
```

should be:

```
1
2
```

because -simply- I called `queueManager.runFirst()` *before* calling `value = 2`

The same issue is applicable to your simple example:

```
var str = "1"
func go() {
    print(str)
}

var array:[()->()] = []
array.append(go)
array[0]()

str = "2"

array.append(go)
array[1]()
```

calling `array.append(go)` won't leads to execute `go()`, you should call it by `array[0]()`; Since you are trying to print the value of the *same* variable (`str`) it will `always` prints the latest value for it. If you want to save each value separately for each function, you should -somehow- declare more than one variable (`value` or `str`).

Comment: I know where the problem is. But i want to call the functions later. But my question is: How can i keep the first value in the first function? I want to store the function with the value of the time of the creation. It should keep the state of the value when i add it. If i would just call it at the position you did, the manager would be completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

var str = "Hello, playground"

class QueueManager {

    typealias FunctionType = () -> ()

    private var functions = [(String, FunctionType)]()

    func add(funcName: String, function: @escaping FunctionType) -> QueueManager {
        functions.append((funcName, function))
        return self
    }

    func runFirst() -> Bool {
        guard functions.isEmpty == false else { return false }
        print(functions)
        functions.first!.1()
        functions.removeFirst()
        return true
    }
}

var value = 1
let queueManager = QueueManager()

func simpleFunction(_ value: AnyObject){
    print(value)
}

queueManager.add(funcName: "simpleFunction"){
    simpleFunction(value as AnyObject)
}

queueManager.add(funcName: "simpleFunction"){
    value = 2
    simpleFunction(value as AnyObject)
}

queueManager.runFirst()
queueManager.runFirst()
```

You have to update your value after the first simpleFunction was added.

Playground Output:

[("simpleFunction", (Function)), ("simpleFunction", (Function))]

1

[("simpleFunction", (Function))]

2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly value is changed elsewhere. I can't update it in the function. I just need to keep the value of value from the time the function was added